# html5 video events when dynamically injected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am injecting a video element into a div on click.

However, I can't get any events to run on that video there after.

Specifically, I want a pause button and for it to fade out when ended.

I can get it to work if I just put in in the html normally - so it must be that it doesn't know it's there when injected?

```
$('#play-video').on( 'click', function() {

  $(this).fadeOut();

  $("#video-container").html("<video controls class='fillWidth' style='width:100%;' id='full-video'><source src='http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/yaddayadda'/><source src='http://sitedsfa.com/yaddayadda' type='video/webm' /></video>");

  $('#close-video').fadeIn();

});

$('#close-video').on('click', function() {
  $('#full-video').pause();
});

$('#full-video').bind('ended', function(){
  alert('video is over');
});
```

In a codepen: [HERE](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/DCIsL)

Any experience with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute `video` element methods on the `$`-wrapped element.

```
 var $video = $('#some-video');
 //**NOT OK**
 $video.play();
 //**OK** - executing the method on the base html video element
 var video = $video[0];
 video.play();
```

### Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DtLBu)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('#play-video').on( 'click', function() {

  $("#video-container").html("<video controls class='fillWidth' style='width:100%;' id='full-video'><source src='http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/yaddayadda'/><source src='http://sitedsfa.com/yaddayadda' type='video/webm' /></video>");

  $(this).fadeOut('fast' , function() { 
                  $("#full-video")[0].play();
                   $('#close-video').fadeIn();
    });

});


$('#close-video').on('click', function() {   $('#full-video')[0].pause(); });

$('#full-video').bind('ended', function(){   alert('video is over'); });
```